# Python3 .format() align usage

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, format

Can anyone help me to change the writing of these lines?
I want to get my code to be more elegant using .format(), but I don't really know how to use it.

```
print("%3s %-20s %12s" %("Id", "State", "Population"))
print("%3d %-20s %12d" %
            (state["id"],
             state["name"],
             state["population"]))
```

Comment: Take a look at this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is easily translated to the `str.format()` [formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
print("{:>3s} {:20s} {:>12s}".format("Id", "State", "Population"))
print("{id:3d} {name:20s} {population:12d}".format(**state))
```

Note that left-alignment is achieved by prefixing the width with `<`, not `-`, and default alignment for strings is to left-align, so a `>` is needed for the header strings and the `<` can be omitted, but otherwise the formats are closely related.

This extracts the values directly from the `state` dictionary by using the keys in the format itself.

You may as well just use the actual output result of the first format directly:

```
print(" Id State                  Population")
```

Demo:

```
>>> state = {'id': 15, 'name': 'New York', 'population': 19750000}
>>> print("{:>3s} {:20s} {:>12s}".format("Id", "State", "Population"))
 Id State                  Population
>>> print("{id:3d} {name:20s} {population:12d}".format(**state))
 15 New York                 19750000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
print("{id:>3s} {state:20s} {population:>12s}".format(id='Id', state='State', population='Population'))
print("{id:>3d} {state:20s} {population:>12d}".format(id=state['id'], state=state['name'], population=state['population']))
```

Note that you have to use `>` to right-align as the items are left-aligned by default. You can also name the items in the formatted string which makes it more readable to see what value goes where.